# Glassfish undeployment does not work on Windows but works fine on Linux

Tags: deployment, glassfish

I am currently working on a web based application using Glassfish. Therefore I have to implement functionality, compile/package it (using maven), deploy the .war file on a glassfish server, test it and undeploy it again to start a new cycle.

My problem is, that Glassfish won't undeploy my .war file under Windows 7. Undeployment takes about 3 minutes and does not remove all deployed files in /glassfish/domains/myDomain/applications. It generates a .glassfishStaleFiles.

To deploy again, I first have to delete the content of /glassfish/domains/myDomain/applications entirely.
Obviously this takes too long and I need to do this many times a day while implementing.

BUT: It all works fine when using Ubuntu. Clean and fast undeployment and deployment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with GlassFish, due to the way file handles are dealt with in Windows compared to Linux. If some process has a file open in Windows, then that will prevent deployment. There are lots of these edge cases in GlassFish many of which (perhaps all) have been fixed in Payara Server, which is derived from GlassFish. Payara Server is free, so [I would recommend trying the latest version 4.1.2.174](https://www.payara.fish/downloads) to see if the issue is resolved there.

Here is an example of some of the fixes for these kinds of issues in Payara Server:
https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/467

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. I am using the mvn Cargo Tool for (un-) deployment, I have many glassfish specific files such as settings.xml, glassfish.xml. DO I have to need to change everything when migrating to Payara?